# file_get_contents('php://input'); does not give me JSON in UTF-8

Tags: php, android, json, encoding, utf-8

i send JSON from my android application and get it with: file_get_contents('php://input');

JSON from application is in correct UTF-8 but from `file_get_contents('php://input');`
i dont get correct UTF-8 JSON
some characters are replaced

example:

```
from application: Lukáš, Pavlovičovo

from file_get_contents: Luká?, Pavlovi?ovo
```

here is my php:

```
<?php    
mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json=trim($json,'"');

$json=utf8_encode($json);

$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

Can you tell me how to get from file_get_contents correct JSON in UTF-8 ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to detect what the encoding is and then convert to utf-8? `$json = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($json), 'UTF-8', $json);` instead of `$json=utf8_encode($json);`

Comment: [Can you figure out why it happens in this example?](https://eval.in/215653)

Comment: slapyo: iconv not work... json_decode dont decode json after iconv

Comment: Ohgodwhy:
Program Output

Lukáš, Pavlovičovo
LukÃ¡Å¡, PavloviÄovo